# iTunes 10-style bottom bar buttons in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, nsbutton

iTunes-like bottom bar buttons seem like some of the standard NSButtonCell styles applied to image templates in Lion: recessed normally, recessed with blue highlight when clicked:

[image: Screenshot]

And yet, I can't find a way to set up NSButton that way.

Missing something obvious? Or is Photoshop + PNG the way to go here?

Comment: You'll have to generate PNG's for every state (on/off/highlighted/active/inactive), and subclass NSButtonCell to get the iTunes-style highlighting as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an NSButton in Interface Builder. Then give it an image (must a template), deselect `Bordered`, set style to `Textured` and mode to `Toggle`.

Comment: Yes! This is probably as close as we can get (won't get the blue highlight because the button is not 'on'). I was missing the 'toggle' part; 'momentary push in' mode causes the background to appear when pushed. Thanks!

Comment: The right type for me was actually Momentary Change, not Toggle, since I wanted those to behave like push buttons (think Add Playlist, not Random).